# Confusion related to the type 3 grammar

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, formal-grammar

I have this confusion. Lets say I have language produced by type 3 grammar such that

```
L(G1) = <Vn1,Vt,P1,S1>
```

I need to find a type3 grammar G3 such that

L(G3) = [L(G1)]*

I can't use S3→S3S1 and S3→null rule in this new G3, because the production is not type 3 as well. So what should I do?

Comment: Are Vn1, Vt, P1, S1 just weirdly named terminals or do they stand for something?

Comment: they are the set of non-terminals, the set of terminals, the set of productions, and the initial symbol, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to arrange things so that whenever $G_1$ would generate a word, $G_3$ will either generate that word, or generate that word and start over. The obvious way to do that is to add to each production $X\to a$ of $G_1$ the production $X\to aS_3$. In addition, you will have to change every instance of $S_1$ to $S_3$ and add the production $S_3\to\lambda$, if $S_1\to\lambda$ wasn’t in the original grammar.

Comment: Is the null character in type 3 grammar?

Comment: @Mike: Yes: the type $3$ grammars are the [regular grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), which allow null productions.

Comment: @Mike: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a language $L$ defined by grammar 
$$S \to a \\ S \to b$$
the language $L^*$ can be defined by
$$S \to a \\ S \to b \\ S \to aS \\ S \to bS$$

Comment: Almost, but you also need to include a production to generate the empty string (which, of course, will always be in $L^*$). As you, I'm still waiting for definitions of Vn1, Vt, P1, and S1.

Comment: @Rick: I have very little doubt that they are the set of non-terminals, the set of terminals, the set of productions, and the initial symbol, respectively.

Comment: @Brian. That was my guess, as well.

Comment: @Rick: W’ve seen the notation before, in exactly this form, though the poster was using a different account.

Comment: @Brian. That being the case, Karolis' hint was pretty good (modulo the empty string).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I"m not the same user, I just copied the notation from him G1 = <N,T,P,S> same thing. Is the null character in type 3 grammar?

Comment: @Mike: I didn’t mean to imply that you were the same person; I really wasn’t sure either way.